# Javascript apply - example in Mixins in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is a piece of code from React documentation.

I am trying to parse what is going on with the when we call setInterval in the component :

```
var SetIntervalMixin = {
  componentWillMount: function() {
    this.intervals = [];
  },
  setInterval: function() {
    this.intervals.push(setInterval.apply(null, arguments));
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.intervals.map(clearInterval);
  }
};

var TickTock = React.createClass({
  mixins: [SetIntervalMixin], // Use the mixin
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {seconds: 0};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.setInterval(this.tick, 1000); // Call a method on the mixin
  },
  tick: function() {
    this.setState({seconds: this.state.seconds + 1});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <p>
        React has been running for {this.state.seconds} seconds.
      </p>
    );
  }
});

React.render(
  <TickTock />,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

- Am I correct to say : when we do

> this.setInterval(this.tick, 1000); // Call a method on the mixin

We call the mixin `setInterval`, which despite having no arguments has a keyword [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Fonctions/arguments) we can use in the body, where we call [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Function/apply) on another [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) from the `Window` namespace, giving `null` as 1st argument, as it is a pure function, and as argument the closure (function + its state closed over) we want to be seen executed, alongside the refresh rate ?

- Bonus question : is there any benefit for not having explicit higher order arguments and say Window.setInterval(callback, interval) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially correct, although it is just applying the array of arguments, not using a closure.

As you imply with the links, there are two concepts here to be familiar with:

First is the [Function arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) variable. Here's key info from its description

> The `arguments` object is a local variable available within all functions

Second is [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply/%22Function.prototype.apply). Here's its description

> The apply() method calls a function with a given `this` value and `arguments`

Therefore, what the React mixin is doing is taking all the arguments passed into the mixin's setInterval function and applying them to the standard setInterval function. It is passing `null` as the `this` parameter, but it could also have passed `window` since that is the object on which setInterval resides. Using `window` would look like this

```
this.intervals.push(setInterval.apply(window, arguments));
```

As for the bonus question, the benefit of using `arguments` is the flexibility it gives because [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) accepts additional parameters after the interval param. However, the example would work just as well using explicit params and avoiding usage of `apply` (assuming you are ok limiting the params to just those explicitly written). In other words, the following example is almost functionally equivalent

```
setInterval: function(func, delay, param1) {
  var intervalId = window.setInterval(func, delay, param1);
  this.intervals.push(intervalId);
},
```

Also, one downside to using `apply` is that it reduces performance since the JIT can't compile it. Most of the time JavaScript code execution is not the performance bottleneck so generally only worry about that is the code in question has been identified as needing performance optimizations.